# How to disable Android GPS receiver while using mock location

Tags: android, xamarin, mocking, gps

While developing a Xamarin.Android app that depends on the GPS location service, I am using a separate custom app to mock movement along a pre-defined route.

The mocking implementation works exactly as expected, and the app under development correctly receives its fixes. However, the device's real GPS service also occasionally interrupts with an actual GPS fix that contradicts the mocked location.

```
[0:] Position: 37.8623530305552, 27.2595232774193 [Mock]
[0:] Position: 37.8623389227154, 27.2594691972361 [Mock]
[0:] Position: 37.8955245, 27.2769657 
[0:] Position: 37.8623248148509, 27.2594151170736 [Mock]
[0:] Position: 37.8623107069617, 27.2593610369318 [Mock]
```

I understand that I can filter out mock locations, but this requires hard-coding my consuming app to know that it is using mock data, whereas I really want it to be agnostic of the source of location data.

I assumed that calling `LocationManager.AddTestProvider` would temporarily disable the real GPS service, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: Adding a test provider adds to **any active providers** on the phone, so you would need to only RequestLocationUpdates from your mock provider.

Comment: @ SushiHangover I am requesting updates from the GPS provider and I have registered a test provider using the same name as the real GPS provider. Should I expect this to replace the real GPS provider or create an additional one?

Comment: AddTestProvider creates/adds to the provider list (GetAllProviders), it does not replace/delete anything.

Comment: OK, so is it possible to delete (or disable) the original provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone facing this issue, the solution is quite simple.

Although my mocking implementation was correctly generating mock GPS location fixes, the mock data was occasionally being contradicted by real location fixes generated by the device.

I initially assumed that this was because the real GPS provider was not being properly suppressed, but it turned out that the unwanted fixes were originating from the **network** provider, which makes sense, since I didn't make any attempt to mock that provider.

A quick solution is to switch the device's location mode to **Device only** (Android Settings > Location > Mode). This ensures that the device will only use GPS as its source of location data.

Alternatively, the mocking implementation can be extended to also add a mock **network** location provider, which then suppresses device location data based on Wi-fi or cellular references.